# Foreach count of model properties in razor page returning incorrect value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, foreach, object-reference

I have a model called Video that has a series of attached feedback comments and feedback comment replies. I have created the following loops within my View to return details of the feedback comments and the associated feedback comment replies but although the count of Model.SelectedScreecast.Feedbacks is 3 I can see that there are 3 feedback records the iteration enters the loop for a 4th time and I am recieving an object reference error. My code is as follows:

```
@foreach (var comment in Model.SelectedScreencast.Feedbacks)
        {
           <li class="comment">
             <div class="avatar"> <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/icons/avatar.png")" width="50" height="50" alt="Avatar" /> </div>
             <div class="comment-meta">
               <h5 class="author"><a href="#">John Doe</a> - <a href="#" class="comment-reply-link">Reply</a></h5>
               <p class="date">January 06, 2011</p>
             </div>
             <div class="comment-body">
               <p>@comment.FeedbackString</p>
             </div>
             <ul class="children">

             @foreach (var reply in @comment.FeedbackReplys)
             {
               <li class="comment">
                 <div class="avatar"> <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/icons/avatar.png")" width="50" height="50" alt="Avatar" /> </div>
                 <div class="comment-meta">
                   <h5 class="author"><a href="#">John Doe</a> - <a href="#" class="comment-reply-link">Reply</a></h5>
                   <p class="date">January 06, 2011</p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="comment-body">
                   <p>reply string</p>
                 </div>
               </li>
             }                     
             </ul>
           </li>
        }
```

I am able to return the expected string when using the following code although this is without the necessary styling for the page.

```
@foreach (var comment in Model.SelectedScreencast.Feedbacks)
        {
           <li>@comment.FeedbackString</li>

             foreach (var reply in @comment.FeedbackReplys)
             {
               <li>@reply.FeedbackReplyString</li>
             }    
}
```

What could cause this to evaluate as object not set to an instance of an object when it is being set through debug checks and when using the code block above. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't set a fourth record as null? Cause it sounds like your foreach counts 4 records instead of 3.
Try to check the view in the debugger and see what the contents of `Model.SelectedScreencast.Feedbacks` are.

Comment: I have checked in debug and it is returning [0][1][2] feebacks with total count being set to 3. I cant understand why it is reading this as four

Comment: Same goes for `comment.FeedbackReplys` ?

Comment: havent managed to get to that part yet its erroring at the first for each

Answer (score 1):

Your foreach is faulty.

`@foreach (var reply in @comment.FeedbackReplys)`

Should be :`@foreach (var reply in comment.FeedbackReplys)`

or even :`foreach (var reply in comment.FeedbackReplys)`.

Razor syntax starts code blocks with a `@` character and does not require explicit closing of the code-block. So the second `@` is redundant, and so might the second `@foreach` `@` be.

Not sure if it will, but hope this solves your problem!

Comment: Hi Wouter thanks for your efforts and advice i will bear this in mind for the future but this is not where the issue is arising unforunately

Comment: Hi Wouter, I have applied your advice and using the simple format of the updated question at the bottom I am at least able to return the values which I knew where there. But when applying html styling it returns object reference error. Any ideas on what might cause that?

Comment: Try using `@:` that inputs the used string directly to the html.
like so: `@: <div class="@myClassVar"><p>hello</p></div>`.
And your update also needs to be:
`foreach (var reply in comment.FeedbackReplys)` instead of `foreach (var reply in @comment.FeedbackReplys)`

Comment: I am using the same methods for podcasts and for screencasts, on podcasts the loop goes through the correct amount of times but in the screencast it is always trying for an additional loop despite the counter being correctly set and this results in a NRE